Use of "which" instead of "whose"?
In this sentence,

A second matter of theological importance in this passage, which feature runs parallel to the first...

Why is "which" used? Shouldn't it be "whose"?

It would be useful to have a complete sentence and a source.

An old-fashioned style choice. I'd use "a feature that runs." "Whose feature" is not the same, though. Whose suggests the feature belongs to some other thing.
